# Class A is in an individual Assembly.How to get instance of List<A> by reflection?

Tags: c#

Class A in ClassLibrary.dll

Source code of ClassLibrary.dll :

```
public class A{}
```

Source code of Main Program:

```
public class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    //How to get Type of List<A> by reflection 
   }
}
```

How to get instance of List by reflection ?

Comment: What do you want? To create a `List` of `A`s with reflection?

Comment: yes.How  to create a List of A

Answer (score 1):

Well, to create a `List` of `A`s using reflection you can do something like:

```
var t = typeof(List<>);
t = t.MakeGenericType(typeof(A));
var list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ClassA]" ,How do you do it this way?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking me

Comment: Like Type t1 = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]");

Comment: If you want something like that do `var t = typeof(Dictionary<,>); t = t.MakeGenericType(typeof(string),typeof(string));` and then cast to an `IDictionary` so you can have access to methods like `.Contains`. Did I make myself clear? BTW, note that `MakeGenericType` receives a `params` of `Type`.